# how can i use the same method for details like restaurant name, location and type?

Tags: swift, segue

//one controller:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "showRestaurantDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                destinationController.restaurantImage = self.restaurantImages[indexPath.row]
}}
```

//2nd controller:

```
@IBOutlet var restaurantImageView:UIImageView!
    var restaurantImage:String!
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'using same method'? You just can set different variables within the `prepareForSegue` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "showRestaurantDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                destinationController.restaurantImage = self.restaurantImages[indexPath.row]

                _ = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                destinationController.restaurantName = self.restaurantNames[indexPath.row]

                _ = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                destinationController.restauranttype = self.restaurantTypes[indexPath.row]

                _ = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                destinationController.restaurantLocation = self.restaurantLocations[indexPath.row]


            }

        }
    }
```

this is what i posted but I'm getting a breakpoint 1.1 at the end parentheses